# AJAX post data undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I'm trying to make an Ajax post request to the root directory on my Express server.

When I just use the HTML form and submit an artist name, I get the response back and can send the information to the client just fine...

See res.send(tourDetails);

When I run the code like this, I get the JSON array back, and I'm good to go.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json());       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
}));

var TourSchedule = require('./artist_profile.js');

app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('layout.jade');
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    var artistName = req.body.artist_name;
    var tour = new TourSchedule(artistName);
    tour.on('end', function(tourDetails){
        res.send(tourDetails);
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Front-end server started on port 3000...');
});
```

But, when I try to add my ajax post request I run into trouble. Replacing res.send(tourDetails) with console.log(artistName), I see that artistName is undefined. So it's recognized when I just use the HTMl form, but it breaks when I introduce my Ajax.

```
$('#artist-form').on('submit', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    $.post('/', function(res){
        var tourInfo = $.parseJSON(res);
        var tourHTML;
        $.each(tourInfo, function(ind, val){
            tourHTML += '<ul class="show-details">';
            tourHTML += '<li class="show-title">';
            tourHTML += tourInfo[ind].title;
            tourHTML += '</li>';
            tourHTML += '<li class="show-date">';
            tourHTML += tourInfo[ind].formatted_datetime;
            tourHTML += '</li>';
            tourHTML += '<li class="show-tickets">';
            tourHTML += 'Tickets: ' + tourInfo[ind].ticket_status;
            tourHTML += '</li>';
            tourHTML += '</ul>';
        });
        $('.artist-tour').append(tourHTML);
    }, 'json');
});
```

Here's the HTML...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>snapTour</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form method="post" id="artist-form">
      <input type="text" id="artist-field" name="artist_name">
      <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
    <div class="artist-tour"></div>
    <script src="../public/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../public/js/jquery.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've been busting my brain over this for hours. Any advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your `$.post` request isn't sending any data at all to the server, you have to actually send the form data

```
$('#artist-form').on('submit', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();

    var data = $(this).serialize();

    $.post('/', data, function(res){
        var tourInfo = $.parseJSON(res);
        var tourHTML;
        $.each(tourInfo, function(ind, val){
            tourHTML += '<ul class="show-details">';
            tourHTML += '<li class="show-title">';
            tourHTML += tourInfo[ind].title;
            tourHTML += '</li>';
            tourHTML += '<li class="show-date">';
            tourHTML += tourInfo[ind].formatted_datetime;
            tourHTML += '</li>';
            tourHTML += '<li class="show-tickets">';
            tourHTML += 'Tickets: ' + tourInfo[ind].ticket_status;
            tourHTML += '</li>';
            tourHTML += '</ul>';
        });
        $('.artist-tour').append(tourHTML);
    }, 'json');
});
```

Comment: It looks like that's not working either.

The weird thing is, typeof req.body still says I'm sending an object, even after serialization.

Comment: So it's not `undefined` anymore, but an object? What do you get when you  `console.log( artistName )` now ?

Comment: Both with and without your changes, console.log(req.body) returns empty object, and console.log(artistName) returns undefined. The only thing I can think of is a problem with my form, but it looks fine.

Here's the github if you feel so enthused.

https://github.com/danemery/snapTour

Comment: You're going to have to do some debugging yourself. Open your browser console (F12) and see that the POST request is being made with the correct data etc. I've testet it, and it seems fine, and the data should be getting to the server

Answer (score 0):

I GOT IT.

Since I'm requesting JSON from another API, I needed to use JSONP when bringing back tourDetails.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json());       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
}));

var TourSchedule = require('./artist_profile.js');

app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('layout.jade');
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    var artistName = req.body.artist_name;
    var tour = new TourSchedule(artistName);
    tour.on('end', function(tourDetails){
        res.jsonp(tourDetails);
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Front-end server started on port 3000...');
});
```

This, combined with serializing the data in Ajax, solved the problem.

Thanks, adeneo!